Understanding 詰めの甘いお上品
From Super no ura de chapter 11, Sasaki (an older guy) told her 三本だったら今日はレジに before cutting off. She knew what he was trying to say:

I need help understanding the meaning of 詰めの甘いお上品.
It seems like 詰めの甘い describes that お上品 is not delivered well. I am also not sure about the usage of お上品. I think お上品 refers to the words he was trying to say. I wonder if it is used in sarcastic manner.


詰めが甘い is a set phrase, and in this scene, it refers to the fact that he could not hide what he was about to say (レジに山田さんがいる). 詰め means "checkmating" (of shogi/chess).
This お上品 is used as a noun, and it seems to be metonymically referring to Sasaki himself. This usage is not very common, so a native speaker who knows the story may take a second to understand this. (And yes, it's sarcasm because she knows the non-上品 side of him.)

So it's something like this:

詰めの甘いお上品。
You always fail at the last moment, Mr. Sophisticated.

